# PHP Issue: password_hash function is not able to generate a salt

Tags: php, hash, password-encryption

I am creating a user registration service provider and in that I am using the password_hash function in order to hash the provided user's password. Below is the code portion used in order to create the hashed string:

```
public function generateHash($string)
    {
        return password_hash($string, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    }
```

As I understood from the PHP manual, we should not generate our salt and instead let the password_hash function take care of that for improved security. However, when I try to create a new user I get the below warning:

> Warning: password_hash(): Unable to generate salt

The application creates the user but due to the above issue no hash will be generated and the password will always be blank in the database

I am using PHP version 7.0.4/Zend Server in my development environment

It would be highly appreciated if someone can point me in the right direction

Comment: Which operating system are you on?

Comment: An empty password will still return a hash.

Comment: From searching, the only place in the PHP source where this error message is generated is [failing to generate random bytes](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c72282a13b12b7e572469eba7a7ce593d900a8a2/ext/standard/password.c#L125-L126). Looking at [random_bytes](http://php.net/random_bytes) you can see the various ways PHP will attempt to generate randomness. I'd start troubleshooting those.

Comment: @jszobody I am using Mac OS X EL Capitan with the specified PHP version above. It looks like it is a development environment related issue because random_bytes() function throws an exception with **Cannot open source device** error message. I need to dig more

Comment: Can you run this command from terminal, ensure you get some random output and not an error? `LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc "a-zA-Z0-9-_\$\?" < /dev/urandom | head -c 10`

Comment: @jszobody I used the command your provided above and I managed to get a random code without any issue.

Comment: Interesting. Googling the "Cannot open source device" error turns up stuff about mcrypt issues, or not being able to read from `/dev/urandom`. Not sure how to help you at this point.

Comment: Thanks a million @jszobody for your help! I will try to read more about that

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the I had an issue with current php7 installation. I switched to PHP5.6 and everything works just fine.

Comment: While that's good to hear, by still not knowing what the issue actually was doesn't really help anyone `:-/`

Comment: If you can discover what causes this (some obscure PHP access issues on the server perhaps?) could you add it to your answer? Cheers.

Comment: Call this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php.
It should throw an exception with an explanation of why it can't gather the random data to generate the salt.